# F# Explicit Interface Method for Two Interfaces

Tags: .net, interface, f#, explicit-interface

What is the correct way to handle this situation. I have one method in my F# class DogTree that should fulfill the requirement of implementing a Bark() method for both interfaces.

```
type ITree =
    interface
        abstract Bark : unit -> unit
        abstract Grow : unit -> unit
    end

type IDog =
    interface
        abstract Bark : unit -> unit
        abstract ChaseCar : unit -> unit
    end

type TreeDog = 
   // so the "and" syntax below doesn't work - what is the correct way to handle?
   interface IDog and ITree with
      member this.Bark() = printfn "Bark"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delegate to a common implementation:

```
type TreeDog = 
  interface IDog with
    member this.Bark() = printfn "Bark" 
  interface ITree with
    member this.Bark() = (this :> IDog).Bark()
```

Or, more appropriately:

```
type TreeDog = 
  member this.Bark() = printfn "Bark"
  interface IDog with
    member this.Bark() = this.Bark() 
  interface ITree with
    member this.Bark() = this.Bark()
```

(Note that this defines an extra method in the class named `Bark`, that is used as the implementation for both interfaces.)

If you declare a primary constructor in your class, you can use this instead:

```
type TreeDog() = // primary constructor
  let bark() = printfn "Bark" // this member is private
  interface IDog with
    member this.Bark() = bark()
  interface ITree with
    member this.Bark() = bark()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is reasonably elegant

```
type TreeDog() = 
  let bark() = printfn "Bark" 
  interface IDog with
    member this.Bark() = bark()
  interface ITree with
    member this.Bark() = bark()
```